# how to install pandas-profiling with markupsafe error

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pandas-profiling

I am trying to install pandas-profiling but I keep getting the error that markupsafe cannot find 2.1.1. version.

```
!pip3 install pandas-profiling 
>>

 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement markupsafe~=2.1.1 (from pandas-profiling) (from versions: 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 1.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for markupsafe~=2.1.1 (from pandas-profiling)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I already tried to run this code

```
!pip3 install MarkupSafe==2.1.1

>>

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MarkupSafe==2.1.1 (from versions: 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 1.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MarkupSafe==2.1.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: First off, you should absolutely follow `pip`'s advice and upgrade. New versions come out all the time and it is worth it to stay up to date.

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and what OS are you running it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkupSafe 2.0.1 [requires](https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/2.0.1/) Python >= 3.6. MarkupSafe 2.1.1 [requires](https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/2.1.1/) Python >= 3.7. From this I can deduce you're using Python 3.6.  Either use MarkupSafe 2.0.1 or upgrade Python to 3.7+.

The bug is reported: https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/issues/1004